# Invoke while loop with expression language

Tags: java, html, jsp, el

I have following while loop in my jsp file:

```
<%
    List sorts = (List)request.getAttribute("sorts");
    Iterator it = sorts.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        out.print(it.next());
}
%>
```

How can I avoid the Java Code in my JSP file here using Expression Language?

I've tried to save the `it.next())` parameter in variables but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use while loop in expression language.instead of while you can use foreach loop.

syntax foreach loop is below-

```
<c:forEach var="name of scoped variable"
       items="Colleciton,List or Array" >
```

where c is prefix

var is variable name where data store from collection.

items is collection or list.

Comment: you know forEach loop is auto increment loop.no need to define next and access values using name of scoped variable.